# Google Play Gamer Titles

Tags: android, google-play-games

Does anyone have a complete list of all the "gamer titles" that it is possible to earn on a Google Play Games profile?

A list of the criteria for earning certain titles would be nice to have as well.

For example, I have had the titles "Pinball Player" and now "Adventurer" because I had the most XP from games in the Arcade and Adventure genres, respectively, and I have a friend whose title is "Pinball Wizard," apparently because the overwhelming majority of his XP comes from Arcade games.

Another one I've seen is "Wanderer," which was given to someone with only a few points, but all of which were in the Adventure genre.

Comment: Answers shouldn't be part of the question.  If you can answer your question, you are free to self answer it.

Comment: I do believe "list answer requests" are considered to broad to be within topic here on Arqade..

Comment: @Timelord64 A list question isn't automatically too broad.  It's an indicator, for sure, but there's more refined criteria to meet.  I'd say this would be answerable.

Comment: I was originally wondering if Google had published an OFFICIAL list somewhere that I couldn't find, although I didn't phrase it that way (I should have.)

Comment: @MatthewBrown No, doing that would get it closed, because Arqade isn't an internet resource location service.  What you've asked is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: "Superhero" also exists, according to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidGaming/comments/3231i3/whats_everyones_google_play_xp_at/cq8a5kl)

Comment: A few more are [here](http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-different-status-the-one-can-achieve-on-Googles-Play-Games-application-And-what-genre-of-games-do-these-statuses-indicate)

Comment: @ZAD-Man ...that's also me. Oops. Thanks, forgot to add those.

Comment: Oh, haha, awkward :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe this is a classic question for community wiki.

Here is the list (if you know another one, add it):

**Adventure Titles**

- Wanderer
- Adventurer

**Arcade Titles**

- Pinball Player
- Pinball Wizard

**Casual Titles**

- Casual Games Master

**Music Titles**

- Rock Star

**Puzzle Titles**

- Puzzle Master

**Racing Titles**

- Drift King
- Drift Master

**Role Playing Titles**

- Wizard
- Archmage

**Strategy**

- General

**Action**

- Superhero

  **Sports**

  - MVP

**FamilyGames**

- Family Games Master

**Word Titles**

- Walking Dictionary

**Simulation**

- Top Gun